# Не получается подключить adColony в libgdx

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, libgdx, admob

Написал игру на LibGDX и пришло время встраивать рекламу. Решил использовать AdMob + AdColony. Сделал всё как написано в [инструкции](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/adcolony). Но при запуске gradle вылетатет ошибка

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:3.1.2.0

вот мой build.gradle для всего проекта (в других gradle-файлах изменений не вносил)

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }

        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "Mechanic World"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.6'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }

        maven { url "https://adcolony.bintray.com/AdColony" } //добавил по инструкции эту строчку
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

        // и вот эти 4
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.adcolony:sdk:3.1.2'
        compile 'com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:3.1.2.0' // эта строчка вызывает проблему
        compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте сделать Build->Clean Project.

Comment: Дйате более развёрнутый ответ. Как Ваш ответ поможет устронить ошибку?

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/188249)

Comment: @aleks.andr почему вы решили, что это не является ответом?

Comment: Какая-то странная реакция на мой ответ. Почему это не может быть решением? Столкнулся с такой же проблемой, решил ее так, как описал выше. Удивило меня, что еще приходится разжевывать ответ) Не стоит обращать внимание на мой рейтинг, я на сайте не зависаю.

Answer (score -1):

Если еще актуально, то нужно добавить в build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    ...
    jcenter()
}
```